# Group by each item in an array, using lodash

Tags: javascript, data-structures, mapping, underscore.js, lodash

I have these kind of data structure from an API, and they told me to group them accordingly.

**INPUT**

```
{
    0: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'foo',
        categories: [
            'Category001',
            'Category002/sub-category001'
        ]
    },
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bar',
        categories: [
            'Category002/sub-category001'
        ]
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bazz',
        categories: [
            'Category001',
            'Category002',
            'Category003'
        ]
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'rem',
        categories: [
            'Category001/sub-category002/nth-category008',
            'Category001/sub-category004',
            'Category003/sub-category001'
        ]
    }
}
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
{
    0: {
        "name": "Category001",
        "isCategory": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "foo",
                "categoryPath": "Category001",
                "isCategory": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "bazz",
                "categoryPath": "Category001",
                "isCategory": false
            },
            {
                "name": "sub-category004",
                "categoryPath": "Category001/sub-category004",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "rem",
                        "isCategory": false,

                    }
                ],
                "isCategory": true
            },
            {
                "name": "sub-category002",
                "categoryPath": "Category001/sub-category002",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "sub-category008",
                        "categoryPath": "Category001/sub-category002/nth-category008",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "name": "rem",
                                "isCategory": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "isCategory": true
                    },

                ],
                "isCategory": true
            },
            {
                "name": "sub-category002",
                "categoryPath": "Category001/sub-category002",
                "isCategory": true
            }
        ],
        "categoryPath": ""
    },
    1: {
        "name": "Category002",
        "isCategory": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "bazz",
                "categoryPath": "Category002",
                "isCategory": false
            },
            {
                "name": "sub-category001",
                "categoryPath": "Category002/sub-category001",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 0,
                        "name": "foo",
                        "isCategory": false,

                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "bar",
                        "isCategory": false,

                    }
                ],
                "isCategory": true
            }
        ],
        "categoryPath": ""
    },
    2: {
        "name": "Category003",
        "isCategory": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "bazz",
                "categoryPath": "Category002",
                "isCategory": false
            },
            {
                "name": "sub-category001",
                "categoryPath": "Category003/sub-category001",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 0,
                        "name": "foo",
                        "isCategory": false,

                    }
                ],
                "isCategory": true
            }
        ],
        "categoryPath": ""
    }
}
```

**Question**

1. Is there an easy way of doing it in lodash?

A simple groupby won't do it though, LOL

```
var groups = _.chain(items)
        .groupBy('categories')
        .pairs()
        .value();
```

Comment: people should start commenting before downvoting.

Comment: There isn't any direct method to do it in lodash, You definately need to write custom logic, give it a try using _.map transformations and then groupBy

Comment: can you give me a direction at least.

Comment: It seems that Haseeb Asif is talking about using https://lodash.com/docs#map and then using https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy . if these don't help let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom processing can not be avoided here in addition to lodash functions. The following is an attempt to use lodash at most:

```
var transformed = _(input)
    .transform(function (result, item) {
        _(item.categories)
            .map(function (categoryPath) {
                return categoryPath.split('/');
            })
            .each(function (categoryPathParts) {

                var dict = result;
                var par;

                var fullpath = _.reduce(categoryPathParts, function (path, category, i) {
                    path += (i > 0 ? '/' : '') + category;
                    if (!(par = _.find(dict, 'name', category))) {
                        dict.push(par = {
                            name: category,
                            categoryPath: (i > 0 ? path : ''),
                            isCategory: true,
                            children: []
                        });
                    }

                    dict = _.find(dict, 'name', category).children;

                    return path;
            }, "")

            par.children.push({
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                isCategory: false,
                categoryPath: fullpath,
            });
        }).value();
    }, [])
    .transform(function (resObj, resCat, i) {
        resObj[i] = resCat;
    }, {});
```

```js
var input = {
    0: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'foo',
        categories: [
            'Category001',
            'Category002/sub-category001']
    },
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bar',
        categories: [
            'Category002/sub-category001']
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bazz',
        categories: [
            'Category001',
            'Category002',
            'Category003']
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'rem',
        categories: [
            'Category001/sub-category002/nth-category008',
            'Category001/sub-category004',
            'Category003/sub-category001']
    }
};

var transformed = _(input)
    .transform(function (result, item) {
        _(item.categories)
            .map(function (categoryPath) {
                return categoryPath.split('/');
            })
            .each(function (categoryPathParts) {

                var dict = result;
                var par;

                var fullpath = _.reduce(categoryPathParts, function (path, category, i) {
                    path += (i > 0 ? '/' : '') + category;
                    if (!(par = _.find(dict, 'name', category))) {
                        dict.push(par = {
                            name: category,
                            categoryPath: (i > 0 ? path : ''),
                            isCategory: true,
                            children: []
                        });
                    }

                    dict = _.find(dict, 'name', category).children;

                    return path;
            }, "")

            par.children.push({
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                isCategory: false,
                categoryPath: fullpath,
            });
        }).value();
    }, [])
    .transform(function (resObj, resCat, i) {
        resObj[i] = resCat;
    }, {});

document.getElementById('resultArea').textContent = JSON.stringify(transformed, null, 2);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="resultArea" rows="111" ></textarea>
```